# How to unselect a uitableview cell when the user returns to the view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a uitableview cell highlighted when a user selects it and then is pushed to a detail view. I would like the cell to be unhighlighted when they return to the table view view controller.

how would I go about accomplishing this?

I'm guessing     `[cell.textLabel setHighlighted:NO];` in viewWillAppear, but cell is undeclared if I put it there.

thanks for any help

Comment: If you are using storyboard then you can just check the clear selection attribute.

Comment: @AlexanderofNorway that property appear only if you use UITableViewController

Answer (score 108, accepted):

If you using `UITableViewController` subclass then just set property

```
self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = YES;
```

else in `viewWillAppear` just call

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
if (indexPath) {
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:animated];
}

// MARK: - Swift 3
if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Note: `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` works most of the time. It will not work if you "swipe to back" on iOS7 back to the tableViewController. The 2nd method works all the time, with added nice animation.

Comment: I think it's better to use viewWillAppear than viewDidAppear - the animation-timing looks more consistent with what UITableViewController does.

Comment: Matter what you want, sure will appear good, maybe even better )

Comment: In swift you do: `if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
            self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: animated)
        }`

Comment: Is better to use `viewWillAppear` than `viewDidAppear`, the effect will be similar to `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear`

Answer (score 22):

**Swift 3.0**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if let selectionIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: selectionIndexPath, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Comment: (You could probably remove the `self.` before each invocation of `tableView`, for some cleaner and swiftier code.)

Comment: For sure. I just like to be explicit about variables that belong to the controller so I don't get them confused with local variables. Just a personal preference.

Comment: @royalmurder You could definitely remove it; it's just a matter of style. I personally prefer to use self to differentiate properties of the class from ivars, as Dustin mentioned. Regardless, the use of self here has no impact on the functionality at hand.

Comment: Worked out of the box in Swift 4 - thanks so much. Tip: You can set `animated:` to `true` (which does the same thing as setting it to `animated` like in this answer) or `false`.

Answer (score 7):

try

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Deselect the row which was tapped
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I decided to make this an answer instead of a comment.

If you are using **storyboard**:
Click on your UITableViewController -> Check the "Selection: Clear on Appearance" box

Answer (score 4):

## swift 3

```
func clearOnAppearance() {
    for indexPath in tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows ?? [] {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or some inelegant way =)

```
NSArray *arrayWithPaths = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
for (NSIndexPath *path in arrayWithPaths)
{
    [tableview deselectRowAtIndexPath:path animated:NO];
}
```