# Short Term Memory Between VCs in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uitableview

**The short version is:**

Do the values of a VC's variables stay in tact during the modal presentation and dismissal of another VC? When the second VC is dismissed, are the original VC's variables still equal to their last values?

**Details, If Needed**

I have a viewController where a table cell is selected. The contents of that cell are then pulled out and passed onto an editor viewController like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    //Segue to mainVC editor, for editing action
    if (segue.identifier == "modalToEditor") && passingEdit == true {
        //Assign selection to a variable 'currentCell'
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! CustomTableViewCell;

        //Set cell text into variables to pass to editor
        let cellNameForEdit = currentCell.nameLabel!.text
        let cellDescForEdit = currentCell.descLabel.text

        //Pass values to EditorView
        let editorVC = segue.destinationViewController as! EditorView;
        editorVC.namePassed = cellNameForEdit
        editorVC.descPassed = cellDescForEdit
        editorVC.indexOfTap = indexPath
        editorVC.currentListEntity = currentListEntity
```

Now, in that second/editor viewController, the user may tap a button asking to move the cell. The "move screen" is a different/third VC. What I want to know is, can I dismiss the editor and expect the original VC to remember the last cell chosen?

- If it will remember, then I'd assume I could then pass it onto the the third/move VC.
- If the original VC cell variable won't still hold that last cell, I'd have to figure out a way to make it remember! Global variable maybe?

**Appending an edit to show the cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //Setup variables
    let cellIdentifier = "BasicCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    //Make sure the row heights adjust properly
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80.0


    //Create normal cells except when last cell
    if indexPath.row < taskList_Cntxt.count {
        let task =  taskList_Cntxt[indexPath.row]
        //Create table cell with values from Core Data attribute lists
        cell.nameLabel!.text = task.valueForKey("name") as? String
        cell.descLabel!.text = task.valueForKey("desc") as? String

        //Related to running TaskActions: Empty block function passed from custom cell VC
        cell.doWork = {
            () -> Void in
            self.doStuff(cell)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Consider copy-pasting code instead of posting screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  View controllers are just objects insofar as their properties are changed only if code is executed that changes them.  In your specific case, the VC keeps its table view as a property (and strongly as a subview of its view), and the table view keeps an array of selected index paths.  Careful though, subclasses of `UITableViewController` can clear the selection by default on viewWillAppear  ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14956916/294949)).

Also note that you've chosen what most would regard a strange approach to initializing the `editorVC` in `prepareForSegue`.  Getting the selected index path is fine, but then getting a cell (a view), then configuring that cell, then getting datasource values from the cell's subviews is very roundabout.

See the line `let task =  taskList_Cntxt[indexPath.row]` in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?  That is how you access an object in the datasource array at the given `indexPath`.  That object (what you've called `task`) should be passed to the downstream view controller.

Comment: Thanks Danh, I posted what you requested. I will try to figure out a way to pass the entire cell. I think I did it the way I did for flexibility. The editor receives cells from more than one table and the cells are different custom types. By passing just the name/desc, I thought I was keeping it simple for the editor.

Comment: :-) not the entire cell.  It should not involve the cell (a view) at all.  Pass the entire **object** you used to configure the cell.  You get that object by indexing your datasource array with the indexPath.row.  I'm sure you do this somewhere in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: Oh.  Didn't see you posted new code:  there it is -> `task = taskList_Cntxt[indexPath.row]`  Pass that `task` to the next vc.

Comment: Also, please, as @zneak suggests.  Paste textual code into the question, then format it by selected it and selecting "{}" on the formatting toolbar.

Comment: Edited again, replaced images with code. Thank you for the help, I'll try out your tip on passing the task tomorrow.