# viewWillAppear not calling didDeselectRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I currently have a `tableView` which I've created custom selection and deselection actions for (fade in and out a view). I am facing a problem where on unwind back to the `tableView` the deselect action isn't being called. I have added the necessary deselect code to my `viewWillAppear` so can't seem to work out what could be going wrong. Is there a different method for this use-case?

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    //Deselect row on unwind
    if let path = folderTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        folderTableView.deselectRow(at: path, animated: true)
    }
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)  {
    print("Select")

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 2:
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! FolderTagTableViewCell
        cell.folderTagSelectionBKG.alpha = 1.0
    default:
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! FolderTableViewCell
        cell.folderSelectionBKG.alpha = 1.0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)  {
    print("Should deselect")

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 2:
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! FolderTagTableViewCell
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            cell.folderTagSelectionBKG.alpha = 0
        })
    default:
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! FolderTableViewCell
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            cell.folderSelectionBKG.alpha = 0
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to clear all the selected cell when view is appear.

Comment: if you want programatically fire  didDeselectRowAt you should use myTableView.delegate?.tableView?(myTableView, didDeselectRowAt: indexpath) in viewWillApper

Comment: @Bhavesh.iosDev You are strongly discouraged from calling any delegate method including `did`, `will` and `should` yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of [deselectRow(at:animated:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614989-de)

> Calling this method does not cause the delegate to receive a `tableView(_:willDeselectRowAt:)` or `tableView(_:didDeselectRowAt:)` message, nor does it send `selectionDidChangeNotification` notifications to observers.
>
> Calling this method does not cause any scrolling to the deselected row.

A solution is to move the code in `didDeselectRowAt` into an extra method

```
func deselectRowAnimated(at indexPath : IndexPath)
{
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 2:
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! FolderTagTableViewCell
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            cell.folderTagSelectionBKG.alpha = 0
        })
    default:
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! FolderTableViewCell
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            cell.folderSelectionBKG.alpha = 0
        })
    }
}
```

and call it in `viewWillAppear` and `didDeleselect`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    //Deselect row on unwind
    if let indexPath = folderTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        deselectRowAnimated(at: indexPath)
    }
}

...

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)  {
    deselectRowAnimated(at: indexPath)
}
```

selectrow

Answer (score 0):

If you using UITableViewController subclass then just set property

```
self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = YES;
```

else on viewDidAppear just call

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
if (indexPath) {
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:animated];
}

// MARK: - Swift 3
if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

[How to unselect a uitableview cell when the user returns to the view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956823/how-to-unselect-a-uitableview-cell-when-the-user-returns-to-the-view-controller)

Comment: Hi, I'm not using a View Controller and I currently have the code in viewDidAppear but it doesn't call 'didDeselectRowAt'

Answer (score 0):

From your tableView unwind action, try to put your deselect code. Like this:

```
@IBAction func <UnwindName>(segue : UIStoryboardSegue) {

    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
       tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```